# Some examples of an inversion

Tags: grammar, inversion

**1) Only Larry sleeps under that tree.** - a standard word order

The right way to rebuild this sentence using the inversion would be

**2) Under that tree sleeps only Larry.**

Now I wonder whether this one is also acceptable?

**3) Under that tree only Larry sleeps.**

Is 3 also an acceptable inversion or is it wrong?

Comment: the tricky word *only* is followed by Larry in all three sentences. Emphasizing the word *only* in any of those ways will convey the same meaning.

Comment: ...actually the stress is on Larry, not on only.

Answer (score 2):

(1) is the most common word order.

(2) is comprehensible, but clumsy.

(3) is an improvement on (2).

Note that there is a context for (2), however, in a narrative register often seen in stories:

> In that castle **lived an evil king**.
>
> On that day **began an adventure** that would take him to the ends of the
>   earth.

Comment: So, you mean that 3 is acceptable for colloquial English, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but only if you're emphasizing the location "under that tree" and I would use a comma to make it clear: Under that tree, only Larry sleeps. Additionally you could italicize Larry to make it even clearer.